# Volume control in the upper-right corner doesn't appear for UID 0 user

Tags: 18.04, root, volume-control

When I'm logged in as a normal user, the volume control is available, but when I'm logged in as a user with root privileges (*i*.*e*., the user has UID 0), the speaker icon doesn't appear.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: By root privileges, do you mean they are `root` or that they can use `sudo`?

Comment: I have user with UID =0 and when I use ID command on this user it shows me that this user is root

Comment: Which linux distro and version are you running? If Ubuntu, why and how did you tweak it to run as the user `root`?

Comment: ubuntu 18.04. I need root privileges to connect to wifi via python script. As a normal user I can see only SSID which I connected.